# How do I prevent my app from getting killed by the system?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I created a Flutter application who sends the location to a server. I need that app to work with the screen turned off. Is there any libraries or commands that I need to implement into the code?

Answer (score 0):

Send the location using an Android Service. take a look at the official doc:

[Android services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: This should be a comment!

Answer (score 0):

On Android you need to get accustomed with the [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) which is an API that makes it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or the device restarts.

There is a Flutter package to help you with the WorkManager:

https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

If you want to make sure uploads or downloads continue, even if your app is put in background or the screen turns off, you might want to check out these packages:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader

Comment: Is it possible to make it works at lower periods of time? (<15 min unlike WorkManager)

Comment: flutter_downloader doesn't support downloading after app is killed.